How do we prove points are isogonal
How would I prove two points X and Y are isogonal in a cyclic quadrilateral ABCD such that Y lies on the intersection of diagonal BD and AC, and X lies in quadrilateral ABCD such that Angles XAD and BAY are congruent and angles XCD and BCA are congruent.
I have attempted to solve this problem using isogonal conjugates. This is what I got so far: AX and AB are isogonal with respect to triangle ABD and CX and CY are isogonal With respect to triangle BCD. Would this be sufficient to prove X and Y are isogonal?

How are $AX$ and $AB$ isogonal wrt triangle $ABD$?

Wouldnt it follow because angle xad and angle bay (or ang bac since c and y r collinear) are congruent

The two points are not isogonal. Have you tried drawing them, with GeoGebra for example?

Did i just waste all my time then

Not quite. $Y$ has an isogonal conjugate wrt the cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ iff $AC \perp BD$.

Y has an isogonal conjugate w X? Why would that be the case?

Because the orthogonal projections of $Y$ onto $AB, BC, CD, DA$ are concyclic (this precisely means $Y$ has an isogonal conjugate) iff $AC \perp BD$.

Is there anyway I can prove this or is it a well known fact? My initial problem statement was to prove that if AC is perpendicular to BD, then XD and XB are perpendicular so that led me to the rabbit hole of proving if it was isogonal or not lol

Then you should have posted the original problem instead! By the way, what is $P$?

Mistype meant to say B instead of P. I wanted to challenge myself but i guess i went down the wrong sol pathway

When $AC\perp BD$, the isogonal conjugate of $Y$ is the circumcenter.

After establishing that, how could i proceed to prove that XD and XB are perpendicular if and only if AC is perpendicular to BD?

$AC\perp BD$ is not sufficient to show that $XD \perp XB$.
